# Responsive Web and Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, responsive-design

When writing responsive web sites, sometimes I need to do `dom` manipulations with `JavaScript`. Often these include calculations involving the screen height or width. After several hours of frustration and using the Google Chrome Emulator, I've discovered that screen height and width is best derived with the `screen.height` and `screen.width` for mobile devices and web browsers with `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`.

With web browsers, if you use the `screen` object it returns the screen size, not the current size of the browser.

*Two questions:*

- Is this the correct approach?
- How do I determine if I'm using a web browser or mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against using JavaScript for responsive displays.

Rather stick to CSS.

You can use media queries to identify the screen size of the device viewing the page.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

You can also do calculations with CSS eg.

```
.moo {
    width: calc(100% - 200px)
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks!  I noticed JavaScript is a pain in the butt for that.

Comment: Personally I have had a lot of success with tables. They adjust nicely on most devices.

Comment: The problem I have is dynamic scrolling, which makes css difficult.   I'm looking at switching to css, but not sure if it is plausible.